# Drupal completion hooks (og)

Tags: php, drupal

Drupal 7.12/organic groups 7.x-1.3

Does anyone know how I can do a quick cURL hit against a site with a few POST vars like group ID, group name, etc. when a user creates a group successfully?

I have no idea how the hooks system works in this case.

Comment: fyi, there's a whole [Drupal stackexchange](http://drupal.stackexchange.org) where you might get more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An organic group is defined as an Entity in Drupal 7, and as such you can implement [`hook_entity_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7) in a custom module to react to a successful group creation:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_insert($entity, $type) {
  if ($type == 'group') {
    $group_id = $entity->gid;

    // Install the Devel module and run the following code to get a full
    // breakdown of what's available in the $entity object
    dpm($entity);

    // Perform your cURL here
  }
}
```

Hope that helps